# putText diagonally using OpenCV and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I have the following code used in my node.js openCV project. The file I'm working on is very similar to [this file](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/blob/master/examples/handGestureRecognition0.js)

```js
result.putText(
  String("hello"),
  finger1,
  cv.FONT_ITALIC,
  2,
  { color: purple, thickness: 2 }
);
```

Is there a way to draw this text at a diagonal, specifying an angle, or two points?

Comment: I don't think so natively in OpenCV, and probably definitely not in opencv.js, but one way you *could* do that would be to rotate the image, draw the text on it, and then rotate back. A lot of unnecessary computation there though. I would probably just use a different lib that can overlay text on images.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Maybe better draw the text into a temp image that just fits it, rotate that, and alpha blend it with the result? (probably don't even need alpha, just masked copy -- not sure if the fonts are antialiased at some scales... although my gut tells me probably not) Better than rotating the whole target image IMHO. I'd guess that might be better than loading something like freetype, grokking it, and dealing with loading the fonts...

Comment: @DanMašek derp, that's a much better solution.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'm kind of confused about how drawing in openCV.js works, you have a function GrabFrame:
```grabFrames('../data/hand-gesture.mp4', delay, (frame) => { //for each frame``` which takes a video and iterates over each of the frames, but I don't understand where the image actually is displayed (where the variable for the image is), and how to edit that image using a "different lib"

Comment: Where did you get the code that does that? I've never used opencv.js but the tutorials don't show iterating through a video like that (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/de/df4/tutorial_js_bg_subtraction.html) for e.g.). Either way, the third parameter in the `grabFrames()` function is an arrow function which passes in `frame` as an argument...so you can likely process the frame inside that function.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, for reference, take a look here: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/blob/master/examples/handGestureRecognition0.js

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yeah, you're right in that inside the function you can process each frame, but my problem is that the frame is in a CV format called "Mat" (short for matrix), and i don't think openCV Mat-types are compatible with other npm image-processing libraries :/

Comment: Oh, I see what you were pointing out then. In that case you just need to encode it and it should be similar to just reading the image as bytes. Idk node image processing libs so can't help out more there. You could still use Dan's suggestion, which is to write the text on a blank image, and roate and overlay it onto your image via masking.